# 一部だけ乱数シードの影響をさせたくない

Tags: python

例えば以下の二つのファイルでtest.pyの2行目でfunc1が呼び出された時点でseedが42に固定されていてbもseed42から生成されたものになります。いまbだけseedを固定させないで発生させたいのです。
func.py

```
import numpy as np
def func1():
    np.random.seed(42)
    return np.random.rand()
```

test.py

```
import func
a = func.func1()
b = np.random.rand()
```

Comment: [numpy.RandomState()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) を使って、新たに生成器を作成すれば良いのではないでしょうか。`b = np.random.RandomState().rand()` ところで、本題とは関係がありませんが、`func.func1()` では内部で seed を一定値で初期化をしているので常に同じ値を返す事になりますが、それはそれでよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis さん、回答としてご投稿頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.RandomState()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) を使って、新たに生成器を作成すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```
b = np.random.RandomState().rand()
```

<sub>-- この回答は、[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50800/%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E4%B9%B1%E6%95%B0%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E5%BD%B1%E9%9F%BF%E3%82%92%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment53061_50800)をコミュニティ wiki 回答として投稿したものです。</sub>

Answer (score 0):

np.random.seedを引数なしで呼ぶことで、別の値で初期化できます。

```
from func import func1
import numpy as np


def func1():
    np.random.seed(42)    # Static seed
    return np.random.rand()


def func2():
    np.random.seed()    # Random seed
    return np.random.rand()


def func3():
    np.random.seed(100)    # Other static seed
    return np.random.rand()


def main():
    val_1 = func1()
    val_2 = func2()
    val_3 = func3()
    print("val_1: {:.2}\nval_2: {:.2}\nval_3: {:.2}\n".format(val_1, val_2, val_3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。